# numpy Reshaping changes the images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

I have an numpy array X which contains 2d images. numpy array dimensions are `(1000,60,40)` (1000=no.of img).

I want to feed this array to my model but requires dimensions to be 
`(1000,60,40,1)` (appended 1 is for no. of channels).

so i reshape the array by

```
Y=X.reshape(1000,60,40,1)
```

as I was having wrong predictions I checked by **re-reshaping the reshaped array** to check  if it was same as my orig img,
I did that by doing

```
Z=Y.reshape(1000,60,40)
```

And I saved them as PNG by doing

```
for i in range(1000):
misc.imsave('img_rereshaped'+str(i)+'.png',Z[i])
```

It gives some png files as output but they are not same as the respective original ones from the X numpy array

Am I reshaping in the wrong way or reshaping changes the input data and again reshaping the reshaped data would give different result than the original data?

Comment: Welcome to SO; for the next time, please check how to properly format your code blocks (done it for you now), and kindly avoid writing whole paragraphs in bold...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test whether the reshaping is causing a problem, it's better to test it without involving other potential errors coming from, say, `misc.imsave()` etc. 
Running something like:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10,3)
b = np.reshape(a, [10, 3, 1])
c = np.reshape(b, [10, 3])
print(np.sum(c - a))
```

you'll see that going back and forth using reshape doesn't cause a problem. 
Could be you're not using the PNG save correctly. Perhaps the function expects 3 channels for example. Try plotting it locally using matplotlib.